# How to convert text {12,13} into int list using EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I am working on an application where I am saving records in text columns like `{ 12, 13, 14 }`. When I try to bind the data into a string property, I get this result:

> System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectArrayIterator`2[System.String,System.Int32]

Below is my query where I need to get the IDs in an integer list. But as we know in `IQueryable` we can't define any split or any methods.

```
public async Task<BaseResponseModel> GetAnswer(int id = 0)
{
    response.SuccessModel();

    try
    {
        var answers = await _context.OfferAnswers
                .Where(s => (id != 0 ? s.id == id : true) && s.is_deleted == false && s.is_active == true)
                .Join(
                    _context.OfferQuestions.Where(q => q.is_active == true && q.is_deleted == false),
                    a => a.question_id,
                    q => q.id,
                    (a, q) => new { answer = a, question = q }
                )
                .Join(
                    _context.Packages.Where(p => p.is_active == true && p.is_deleted == false),
                    q => q.question.package_id,
                    p => p.id,
                    (q, p) => new { answer = q.answer, question = q.question, package = p }
                )
                .Select(s => new
                {
                    PackageId = s.question.package_id,
                    Package = s.package.package_name,
                    QuestionId = s.answer.question_id,
                    Question = s.question.question,
                    AnswerId = s.answer.id,
                    AddOnIds = s.answer.addon_ids,
                    Answer = s.answer.answer,
                    Description = s.answer.description,
                    url = s.answer.icon,
                    AnswerType = s.answer.answer_type_id,
                    Product = s.answer.product_ids == null ? null :
                        _context.Products
                            .Join(
                                _context.PackageDetails
                                    .Where(pd => pd.is_active == true && pd.is_deleted == false && pd.package_id == s.question.package_id),
                                p => p.id,
                                pd => pd.product_id,
                                (p, pd) => new { product = p, productdetail = pd }
                            )
                            .Select(p => new
                            {
                                ProductId = p.product.id,
                                ProductName = p.product.product_name
                            })
                            .ToList(),
                    Addon = s.answer.addon_ids == null ? null :
                        _context.add_Ons
                            .Join(
                                _context.PackageDetails
                                    .Where(ad => ad.is_active == true && ad.is_deleted == false && ad.package_id == s.question.package_id),
                                a => a.id,
                                ad => ad.add_on_id,
                                (a, ad) => new { addon = a, addondetail = ad }
                            )
                            .Select(a => new AddonDto
                            {
                                AddonId = a.addon.id,
                                AddonName = a.addon.add_on_name,
                                ListIds = s.answer.addon_ids
                            })
                            .ToList()
                })
                .ToListAsync();
        response.Data = id != 0 ? answers.FirstOrDefault() : answers.ToList();
        response.ResponseMessage = "Packages fetched successfully.";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }

    return response;
}
```

`AddOnDto` class:

```
public class AddonDto
{
       public AddonDto()
       {
           this.AddonIds = new List<int>();
       }

       public int AddonId { get; set; }
       public string? AddonName { get; set; }
       public List<int> AddonIds { get; set; }
       private string _listIds; // backing field for ListIds
       public string ListIds {get; set;}
}
```

Here is the screenshot of the table:

[image]

Comment: I think this is a horrible way to write linq spaghetti code. Very hard to read and not optimal.

Comment: I know its hard to read but I am gonna refactor it once resolved the issue I am facing

Comment: EF should already know (or be told) how to get from OfferAnswers to OfferQuestions and Packages, so you could just do a filtered include, no need for all this LINQ join stuff - it's EF's buiness to write joins, when it sees you using the navigation proeprties that travel from one entity to another

Comment: As to your actual query, if you're not using a version of EF that can handle JSON columns, you can consider downloading the data into a mapped string property, and having a notmapped object property that deserializes the data the first time, and stores the deserialized result for repeated work. The getter for the string can reserialize the object to string; you work with the object and de/ser happens automatically. If your EF is recent enough, it can just work with a JSON column directly

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should consider using a properly normalized schema with a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship since that can properly be indexed and searched more efficiently than with strings. In cases where you do need to store something like a delimited list as a string you can use an unmapped property that transforms the string into the desired structure:

public class AddonDto
{
public int AddonId { get; set; }
public string? AddonName { get; set; }
private string _listIds;
public string ListIds
{
get => _listIds;
set
{
_listIds = value;
_addonIds = null;
}
}

```
   private List<int>? _addonIds = null;
   [NotMapped] // If this is an entity class so EF doesn't try and map this property.
   public IReadOnlyCollection<int> AddonIds 
   { 
       get 
       {
           return _addonIds ??= new List<int>(ListIds
               .Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
               .Select(x => int.Parse(x));
       }
   }
```

}

If you want to alter the associated add-ons then expose an action method like "AddAddon(int)" and "RemoveAddon(int)" which can add or remove a desired Id to the backing collection and update the ListIds string. Note that if the ListIds string allows a setter then the backing collection should be erased to ensure that it is re-calculated to reflect the current strings.

When it comes to delimited strings within entities I recommend using an edged delimiter where a delimiter character is always found on either side of each entry. For example with a pipe delimiter instead of "1,2,3,4" you would have "|1|2|3|4|" The above split-based logic will work for either delimiter pattern/character but when querying data efficiently in Linq you cannot use "AddonIds" (`List<int>`) in the Linq query, you would need to do a `Contains` against the string backing field. With edged delimiters you can do something like `.Where(x => x.ListIds.Contains($"|{addonId}|"))` to find entries containing a delimited addonId value. With comma-delimited lists, searching for  Id #1 would find "1", "10", "11", "21" if you do a `.Where(x => x.ListIds.Contains(addonId))` and you cannot rely on `.Where(x => x.ListIds.Contains($",{addonId},"))` since that won't find entries where "1" is the first or last entry. With edge-delimiters it would look specifically for entries containing "|1|" whether "1" is on the front, back, or middle, and only match cases where "1" was found, not "|10|" for instance.